# Adding a gradient to Google-Visualization ColumnChart

Tags: svg, gradient, google-visualization

I'm trying to add some pizazz to a Google ColumnChart by adding a gradient to the SVG rects that are drawn for the columns. The code below will add gradients to the iframe svg>defs and replace the fill attribute of the rects correctly in all the browsers I care about at this moment (later versions of Firefox, IE and Chrome).

My problem is that whenever I hover over or select a bar (or the legend), the color is reset back to the original color. I'm an SVG noob and I haven't been able to figure how, where or what is resetting the color.

So my question is does anyone know how (using javascript/jquery) to stop, overwrite or someway manipulate the code that resets the colors? I would prefer to keep the 'interactive' parts intact (tooltip, etc.) if possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Visualization API Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
      google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        var rowData = [['Year', 'North', 'West',  'South'],
                       ['2010', 197,     333,     298    ],
                       ['2011', 167,     261,     381    ]];
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rowData);

        visualization = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));

        google.visualization.events.addListener(visualization, 'ready', function(){
          var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
          var gradients = [["red","#C0504D","#E6B8B7"],
                           ["green","#9BBB59","#D8E4BC"],
                           ["blue","#4F81BD","DCE6F1"]];
          var svg_defs = $("#visualization iframe").contents().find('defs');
          // add gradients to svg defs
          for(var i = 0; i < gradients.length; i++){
            var grad = $(document.createElementNS(svgns, "linearGradient")).
                attr({id:gradients[i][0],x1:"0%",x2:"0%",y1:"0%",y2:"100%"});
            var stopTop = $(document.createElementNS(svgns, "stop")).
                attr({offset:"0%","stop-color":gradients[i][1]});
            var stopBottom = $(document.createElementNS(svgns, "stop")).
                attr({offset:"100%","stop-color":gradients[i][2]});
            $(grad).append(stopTop).append(stopBottom);
            svg_defs.append(grad);
          }
          // #3366cc, #dc3912, #ff9900 - replace default colors with gradients
          $("#visualization iframe").contents().find('rect[fill="#3366cc"]').attr({'fill':'url(#blue)','stroke-width':0.4,'stroke':'#000000'});
          $("#visualization iframe").contents().find('rect[fill="#dc3912"]').attr({'fill':'url(#blue)','stroke-width':0.4,'stroke':'#000000'});
          $("#visualization iframe").contents().find('rect[fill="#ff9900"]').attr({'fill':'url(#blue)','stroke-width':0.4,'stroke':'#000000'});
        });
        // Create and draw the visualization.
        visualization.draw(data,{width:600, height:400});
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

So while looking through the DOM to see if I could find where these color codes might be stored (and there by find the functions that are using them), I did find these (which when set will do what I want):

```
      //fill
      visualization.qa.l.e[0].Hm.O = "url(#blue)";
      visualization.qa.l.e[1].Hm.O = "url(#red)";
      visualization.qa.l.e[2].Hm.O = "url(#green)";

      // stroke
      visualization.qa.l.e[0].Hm.Jb = "#000000";
      visualization.qa.l.e[1].Hm.Jb = "#000000";
      visualization.qa.l.e[2].Hm.Jb = "#000000";

      // fill-opacity
      //visualization.qa.l.e[0].Hm.$b = 0.5;
      //visualization.qa.l.e[1].Hm.$b = 0.5;
      //visualization.qa.l.e[2].Hm.$b = 0.5;

      // stroke-width
      visualization.qa.l.e[0].Hm.H = 0.4;
      visualization.qa.l.e[1].Hm.H = 0.4;
      visualization.qa.l.e[2].Hm.H = 0.4;

      // stroke-opacity
      //visualization.qa.l.e[0].Hm.nc = 0.5;
      //visualization.qa.l.e[1].Hm.nc = 0.5;
      //visualization.qa.l.e[2].Hm.nc = 0.5;
```

but this would be only a temporary solution as I'm sure the next time Google updates the Visualization code, these variable names will change (I don't think someone choose these on purpose and the compressor/obfuscator used would probably pick different variable names next time - but then who knows - maybe it won't).

So if anyone knows of a more permanent way that doesn't depend on manually finding and setting the variable names, I would love it. Otherwise, this may be my best bet for now.

**UPDATE2** (March 1, 2012)

Case in point. The variables are now moved:

```
      //fill
      visualization.da.C.d[0].en.S = "url(#blue)";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `MutationObserver` to know when changes have been made to the svg

move the code from the `'ready'` event listener to the `observer`
to *overwrite the code that resets the colors*

as in the following snippet...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Visualization API Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
      google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        var rowData = [['Year', 'North', 'West',  'South'],
                       ['2010', 197,     333,     298    ],
                       ['2011', 167,     261,     381    ]];
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rowData);

        var chartDiv = document.getElementById('visualization');
        visualization = new google.visualization.ColumnChart();

        // observe changes to the chart container
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
          var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
          var gradients = [["red","#C0504D","#E6B8B7"],
                           ["green","#9BBB59","#D8E4BC"],
                           ["blue","#4F81BD","DCE6F1"]];
          var svg_defs = $("#visualization iframe").contents().find('defs');
          // add gradients to svg defs
          for(var i = 0; i < gradients.length; i++){
            var grad = $(document.createElementNS(svgns, "linearGradient")).
                attr({id:gradients[i][0],x1:"0%",x2:"0%",y1:"0%",y2:"100%"});
            var stopTop = $(document.createElementNS(svgns, "stop")).
                attr({offset:"0%","stop-color":gradients[i][1]});
            var stopBottom = $(document.createElementNS(svgns, "stop")).
                attr({offset:"100%","stop-color":gradients[i][2]});
            $(grad).append(stopTop).append(stopBottom);
            svg_defs.append(grad);
          }
          // #3366cc, #dc3912, #ff9900 - replace default colors with gradients
          $("#visualization iframe").contents().find('rect[fill="#3366cc"]').attr({'fill':'url(#blue)','stroke-width':0.4,'stroke':'#000000'});
          $("#visualization iframe").contents().find('rect[fill="#dc3912"]').attr({'fill':'url(#blue)','stroke-width':0.4,'stroke':'#000000'});
          $("#visualization iframe").contents().find('rect[fill="#ff9900"]').attr({'fill':'url(#blue)','stroke-width':0.4,'stroke':'#000000'});
        });

        observer.observe(chartDiv, {
          childList: true,
          subtree: true
        });

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        visualization.draw(data,{width:600, height:400});
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [here is a working example to change the bar color on a gantt chart using `MutationObserver`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40655754/5090771)