# Change the bar color in gantt chat based on value

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, gantt-chart

I would like to change the color of the bar in the gantt chart based in the value I am passing. When `Percent done` equals of higher than 100 the bar should be red. Is it possible?

https://jsfiddle.net/1cez1duf/

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt'], 'language': 'pt-br'});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
    data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
    data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Percent done');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

    data.addRows([    
        ['C10', 'C10', 'Xa', new Date(2015, 3, 20), new Date(2016, 8, 30), null, 109, null],
        ['C15', 'C15', 'Xa', new Date(2016, 5, 2), new Date(2016, 9, 31), null, 111, null],
        ['C20', 'C20', 'Xa', new Date(2016, 8, 15), new Date(2016, 10, 25), null, 88, null],
        ['C21', 'C21', 'Xa', new Date(2016, 8, 1), new Date(2016, 10, 25), null, 90, null]
    ]);

    var options = {
        width: "100%",
        hAxis: {
            textStyle: {
                fontName: ["Roboto Condensed"]
            }
        },
        gantt: {
            labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 12,
                color: '#757575'
            }
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there aren't any standard options to change bar color by value

but you can change the chart elements manually

recommend using a `MutationObserver` as the chart will try to change the bar color back to the default, on any interactivity such as hover or select

the order of the bars should follow the rows in the `data`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['gantt']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
  data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
  data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Percent done');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

  data.addRows([

  ['C10', 'C10', 'Xa', new Date(2015, 3, 20), new Date(2016, 8, 30), null, 109, null],
  ['C15', 'C15', 'Xa', new Date(2016, 5, 2), new Date(2016, 9, 31), null, 111, null],
  ['C20', 'C20', 'Xa', new Date(2016, 8, 15), new Date(2016, 10, 25), null, 88, null],
  ['C21', 'C21', 'Xa', new Date(2016, 8, 1), new Date(2016, 10, 25), null, 90, null]
  ]);

  var options = {
    width: '100%',
    hAxis: {
      textStyle: {
        fontName: ['Roboto Condensed']
      }
    },
    gantt: {
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
        color: '#757575'
      }
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(container);

  // monitor activity, change bar color
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('path'), function(bar, index) {
      if (data.getValue(index, 6) > 100) {
        bar.setAttribute('fill', '#a52714');
      }
    });
  });
  observer.observe(container, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

it appears when there is partial completion, the "bar" is split with two colors
the lighter shade being represented by a `'rect'` element
you could change this to a lighter shade of red
use the Y coordinate of the `'path'` to find the correct `'rect'`

also, need to sort the data in the same order as displayed in the chart...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['gantt']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
  data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
  data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Percent done');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

  data.addRows([
    ['C10', 'C10', 'Xa', new Date(2016, 2, 23), new Date(2016, 10, 30), null, 94.84, null],
    ['C15', 'C15', 'Xa', new Date(2016, 4, 1), new Date(2016, 11, 29), null, 82.64, null],
    ['C20', 'C20', 'Xa', new Date(2016, 7, 1), new Date(2016, 10, 25), null, 93.1, null],
    ['C25', 'C25', 'Xa', new Date(2016, 3, 11), new Date(2016, 10, 25), null, 96.49, null],
    ['C30', 'C30', 'Xa', new Date(2016, 9, 3), new Date(2017, 1, 28), null, 30.41, null],
    ['C35', 'C35', 'Xa', new Date(2016, 3, 8), new Date(2016, 5, 24), null, 113.78, null]
  ]);
  data.sort([{column: 3}]);

  var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    xWidth = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    yHeight = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;

  var options = {
    height: 600,
    width: "100%",
    hAxis: {
      textStyle: {
        fontName: ["Roboto Condensed"]
      }
    },
    gantt: {
      labelStyle: {
      fontName: ["Roboto Condensed"],
      fontSize: 12,
      color: '#757575'
      }
    }
  };
  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(container);

  // monitor activity, change bar color
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('path'), function(bar, index) {
      var barY;
      if (data.getValue(index, 6) > 100) {
        bar.setAttribute('fill', '#b71c1c');
        barY = bar.getAttribute('d').split(' ')[2];
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(bar) {
          if (bar.getAttribute('y') === barY) {
            bar.setAttribute('fill', '#f44336');
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
  observer.observe(container, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this helps! But in one of my tests i faced a situation that does't render quit well, see: https://jsfiddle.net/1cez1duf/1/. What do you think it could be? Thanks for any info. When I mouseover it, it says `is on a critical path`

Comment: see __EDIT__ to above answer -- as for _critical path_, you can turn off with `criticalPathEnabled: false`

Comment: Thanks but the bar are getting red in wrong bar. See: C35 is the one with more than 100 but is blue and should be red. And C30 has 30.41 and it is red and should be blue. Thanks again for any info on this. It will help me a lot

Comment: didn't notice that, answer assumes bars are in the same order as the data -- let me think on that one, need a way to relate the bar back to the data...

Comment: I see what you did. Gonna try fix it at my side. Thanks.

Comment: sorting the data the same as displayed by the chart should fix the issue, changed the __EDIT__ above...

Comment: Yes, I was about to working with the order by in the select. Thanks again for your code. Works great.