# Google Gantt Chart not Changing Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, css, google-visualization

I am using google gannt chart. I already populate the data in my json data, but my problem is how can i changed the color of each chart dynamically? or different color of chart of each data.

heres my code

```
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    var project_id = pathArray[3];

    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/milestone/project/pmt/api/' + project_id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (jsonData) {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                  data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
                  data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
                  data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
                  data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
                  data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
                  data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
                  data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
                  data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

                for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {

                data.addRows([
                        [jsonData[i]._id, jsonData[i].subject, jsonData[i].status,
                         new Date(jsonData[i].kick_off), new Date(jsonData[i].due_date), null, 100, null]
                     ]);
                }

                var options = {
                  height: 400,
                  gantt: {
                    trackHeight: 30
                  }
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

                chart.draw(data, options);
            }

        });
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle?

Comment: the `'Resource'` column can be used to group the bars by color, but no config option to control _which_ color -- however, colors can be set manually using script, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40655754/5090771)...